# react native callkeep can not navigate to special screen in case app killed

Tags: react-native, call

I am using RNCallkeep to handle call inside my App.

In case app active or in background, when user answer call, I using this code to navigate into Call Screen:

***App.js file***

```
RNCallKeep.addEventListener('answerCall', answerCall)


const answerCall = ({callUUID}) => {
  console.log(`[answerCall] ${callUUID}`)
  RNCallKeep.setCurrentCallActive(callUUID)
  const callData = CallManager.getInstance().getAllCall().find(c => c.callId.toString().toUpperCase() === callUUID.toString().toUpperCase())
  if(callData){
    const masterInfo = JSON.parse(storage.getString(STORAGE_PARAMS.MASTER_INFO))
    const data = callData.data
    const mediaServers = JSON.parse(data.mediaServerAddress ?? data.MediaServerAddress)
    const iceServsers = JSON.parse(data.iceServers ?? data.IceServers)
    
    const roomJanusInfo = data
    const room = { RoomId: data.roomId ?? data.RoomId, ServiceId: data.roomServerId ?? data.RoomServerId, RoomName: data.callerDisplay ??  data.CallerDisplay }
    const isVideo = data.video ?? data.Video === 'True'
    const isAudio = true
    const isOutgoing = false
    const callUser = { Id: data.callerId ?? data.CallerId, ServiceId: data.callerServiceId ?? data.CallerServiceId, Name: data.callerDisplay ?? data.CallerDisplay }
    const roomAddress = mediaServers[0]
    const videoRoomId = data.videoRoomId ?? data.VideoRoomId
    const videoRoomPwd = data.videoRoomPwd ?? data.VideoRoomPwd
    const audioRoomId = data.audioRoomId ?? data.AudioRoomId
    const audioRoomPwd = data.audioRoomPwd ?? data.AudioRoomPwd

    const roomController = RoomCallService
    const url = `${baseurl(room.ServiceId, masterInfo)}${roomController.Controller}/${roomController.ContactCallUpdateSubStatus}`
    const params = {
      RoomId: room.RoomId,
      CallId: data.callId ?? data.CallId,
      SubStatus: VxLinkCallSubStatus.Accepted,
      ClientType: ClientType.MobileApp
    }
    postData(url, params, '_ContactCallUpdateSubStatus')
      .then(result => {
        console.log('_ContactCallUpdateSubStatus success', result)
        navigate('SingleCall', {
          room: room,
          callUUID: callUUID,
          isVideo: isVideo,
          isAudio: isAudio,
          isOutgoing: isOutgoing,
          callUser: callUser,
          roomAddress: roomAddress,
          videoRoomId: parseInt(`${videoRoomId}`),
          videoRoomPwd: videoRoomPwd,
          audioRoomId: parseInt(`${audioRoomId}`),
          audioRoomPwd: audioRoomPwd,
          iceServers: iceServsers,
          roomJanusInfo: roomJanusInfo //for other purposes
        })
      }).catch(error => {
        alert(error)
        console.log('_ContactCallUpdateSubStatus error', error, url, params)
      })
  }
}
```

It's work fine, but in case app killed. I can not navigate into SingleCall screen, and I can not debug anything after force kill app

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wake up your application.

Receiving a call when the application is not reachable.

In some case your application can be unreachable :

when the user kill the application when it's in background since a long time (eg: after ~5mn the os will kill all connections). To be able to wake up your application to display the incoming call, you can use https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-voip-push-notification on iOS or BackgroundMessaging from react-native-firebase-(Optional)(Android-only)-Listen-for-FCM-messages-in-the-background).

You have to send a push to your application, like with Firebase for Android and with a library supporting PushKit pushes for iOS.

https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep#receiving-a-call-when-the-application-is-not-reachable